# VBA Creat chart based on pass/fail criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I have code that creates a scatter plot (time vs. a column of data). There is a third column that states whether the data "passed" or "failed" (the data comes from a group of samples going through testing).

I'm wondering, is there an algorithm that can sort through the third column, and based on if it says "passed" or "failed", it adds the corresponding time and data cells that are offset in the same row to a series? There would be two series: one for passed and one for failed. The x values are time and the y values are data.

My code already written is as follows for creating the chart with the series and how it finds the range of data (changes dynamically):

```
Sub AddCharts()

Dim TSht As Worksheet
Dim Cht as Chart

With TSht

'Find last row in data
LRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'Create Chart
Set Cht = .Shapes.AddChart.Chart
    With Cht
    .ChartType = xlXYScatter
    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        With .SeriesCollection(1)
        .XValues = TSht.Range(Cells(2, 6), Cells(LRow, 6))
        .Values = TSht.Range(Cells(2, 7), Cells(LRow, 7))
        End With
    End With
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: If you ask a new question which is basically the same as one you *just asked only an hour ago*, maybe you should consider deleting the first one, or at least put a pointer there to the latest question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested:

```
Sub AddCharts()

Dim TSht As Worksheet
Dim Cht As Chart, LRow As Long
Dim xP As Range, yP As Range, xF As Range, yF As Range
Dim rng As Range, c As Range

    Set TSht = ActiveSheet

    With TSht

    'Find last row in data
    LRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'e.g. Pass/Fail is in Col 5
    Set rng = .Range(.Cells(2, 5), .Cells(LRow, 5))
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        If c.Value = "Pass" Then
            AddTo xP, c.Offset(0, 1)
            AddTo yP, c.Offset(0, 2)
        End If
        If c.Value = "Fail" Then
            AddTo xF, c.Offset(0, 1)
            AddTo yF, c.Offset(0, 2)
        End If
    Next c

    'Create Chart
    Set Cht = .Shapes.AddChart.Chart
        With Cht
            .ChartType = xlXYScatter

            With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
                .Name = "Pass"
                .XValues = xP
                .Values = yP
            End With

            With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
                .Name = "Fail"
                .XValues = xF
                .Values = yF
            End With

        End With
    End With

End Sub

'utility sub for building up X and Y ranges
Sub AddTo(rng As Range, rngAdd As Range)
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        Set rng = rngAdd
    Else
        Set rng = Application.Union(rng, rngAdd)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you Tim. Also, I know I posted the same question, I should have just edited it or deleted it, I'm fairly new to stackoverflow so thanks for the heads up. Just thought this format was a lot easier to understand what I was trying to do

Comment: No problem - typically it's best to edit your original question: that way no-one spends time trying to help on a problem that already has an answer somewhere else.